# C++ change value in const char

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a const char

```
const char example[] = "\x4D\x5A\xE8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x5B\x52\x45\x55\x89\xE5\x81\xC3";
```

and

```
DWORD* example2 = "\xAA\xBB\xCC\xDD";
```

and i want to change the last 4 bytes of example1 with those on example2 
what can I do in C++?

i have tried `memcpy` , `strcpy` and `strcpy_s` with no luck

Comment: Why would you declare it `const` if you want to modify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Donot modify a constant string.
2. `const char example[] = "\x4D\x5A\xE8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x5B\x52\x45\x55\x89\xE5\x81\xC3";` here, your string has a few NULL string terminator. This will NOT work with functions in `<string.h>` (such as strlen() and others)
3. Instead use `memcpy`, `memset` functions to append ONLY after knowing the length of the binary string.
4. Store your result in a character array, but don't assume it will work as a regular string because of your data.

Comment: `example[]` char array contains `x00` in the middle, so `strlen` will not work properly

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL I know changed when I saw :)

Answer (score 9):

You should not modify a constant array!
Modifying a inherently constant object/variable leads to **Undefined Behavior**.
Just don't do it. Make a copy of it and modify that copy or if you want to modify the same array simply don't declare it as `const`.

Answer (score 2):

your `example[]` char array is defined as `const`  so you can not modify it.

1) You should get an eror in the compilation if you change your const char array in this way

```
example[2] ='R';
```

2) You should get a warning if you modify your const char array via `memcpy` or via `strcpy`

Change it to

```
char example[] = "\x4D\x5A\xE8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x5B\x52\x45\x55\x89\xE5\x81\xC3";
```

And you can not use `strcpy` because your character array contains `x00` in the middle so this will affect the `strcpy` function.  Because `strcpy` stop when it find `x00` in the char array

`example[]` char array contains `x00` in the middle, so to find the length of `example[]` with `strlen` will not work properly. For this case I suggest to use `sizeof(example)` instead.

Here after how you can make your copy:

```
char example[] = "\x4D\x5A\xE8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x5B\x52\x45\x55\x89\xE5\x81\xC3";
DWORD* example2 = "\xAA\xBB\xCC\xDD";

if (sizeof(example)>=sizeof(example2))
     memcpy(example+sizeof(example)-sizeof(example2), example2, sizeof(example2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never modify a constant including a constant array. If you want to change what you have above, create a copy of it and change the **copy**. As pointed out by RasmusKaj strcpy will not help you here as the source strings contains zero chars so maybe use memcpy for the creation of the copy.

Comment: Correct, except that strcpy can only be used on null-terminated strings.  The example char array here contains non-terminating null characters, so str* functions will not work on it.

Comment: @RasmusKaj thank you did not notice that. I edited my answer. I believe than the OP either has to use memcpy or do the copy with a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Const variables can't be changed.  This is by design.  In the case of a c string, you can have the contents of the string const or the pointer to the string const.

Since you are defining it as a const character array, the pointer is implicitely const and the contents are explicitly const.

```
const char * const mystring = "hello"
```

In this case the first "const" tries to apply left (there is nothing), so it applies right (to the char type).  So the string content may not change.  The second const tries to apply left, so it makes the pointer itself const.  That means that the mystring pointer must always point to where the "h" from "hello" in memory is.

So afterwards if I try:

```
mystring[0] = "y"
```

or

```
mystring = "gooodbye!"
```

They would not work.  If you removed the first or second const respectively, they could be made to work.

The purpose of const allows you to say ahead of time "this variable cannot be modified".  That means that if it is modified then there is a problem.  Generally you should always use const with any variable that you do not want to be modified after instantiation.